# Download xml to app folder from url

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, download

I want to make a android app white play times of the cinema in my land. All the data is in xml on my server (php) but now i need to download the data to my folder on the phone. I want download and not parser so wen the user is offline the data is still ther.

I have tried manny online examples but they give me all a error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1Dyd.png

What is the best and easy way to make a download.
I now php, sql, javascript, jquery, but no java. I learn from making thins ;)

Greatings Christophe VD

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to start network task from main UI thread.
Look at this error in the logcat

```
caused by android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Try your code samples again but wrap it to anync task before.
Like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/4186991

Comment: i have add it but i get a new error

class downloaddata extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Download> {
protected Download doInBackground() {


http://s17.postimg.org/cawz3x7z3/test.png